# проверка элементов списка в словаре

Tags: python, словари

Добрый день. либо не смог верно сформулировать запрос, либо плохо гуглил.

```
d = {1 : {'y' : 'x', 'list' : ['a' , 'b' , 'c']}
     2 : {'y' : 'x', 'list' : ['q' , 'w', 'e']}
    }
```

Не могу сообразить. Необходима функция, по ключу( 1 или 2) получить один из списков и проверить наличие элемента в нём, если такого элемента нет, вернуть None, если есть True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы это имели ввиду?

```
In [4]: d
Out[4]:
{1: {'list': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'y': 'x'},
 2: {'list': ['q', 'w', 'e'], 'y': 'x'}}

In [5]: def foo(key, value):
   ...:     if value in d[key]['list']:
   ...:         return True
   ...:     return None
   ...:

In [6]: foo(1, 'a')
Out[6]: True

In [7]: foo(1, 'e') # None
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Это работает.

Comment: @Alban будет KeyError в случае отсутствия key в d

Comment: @FedirAlifirenko сам собой, но какой смысла подставлять под данное решение не рабочий пример? Автор задал конкретный вопрос.

Comment: @Alban почему не рабочий?
Пример как раз таки под конкретный вопрос автора.

Comment: @FedirAlifirenko Вы меня не поняли, ваш пример хорош (минусы не мои), но не стоит условие что ключа к примеру может и не быть, автор не собирается использовать это решение на словаре не подходящем для него.

Comment: @Alban спасибо за разъяснения.

Answer (score -2):

Еще один из вариантов.

```
d = {
    1: {'list': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'y': 'x'},
    2: {'list': ['q', 'w', 'e'], 'y': 'x'},
}   

def foo(k, v):
    return None if not d.get(k) or 'list' not in d.get(k) else v in d.get(k).get('list')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(foo(3, 'a'))  # None
    print(foo(2, 'w'))  # True
    print(foo(2, 'b'))  # False
```